# Next js + AWS S3 + Auth.Js/next-auth + Planetscale "ConnectTimeoutError" on Uploading Files

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next-auth

I am trying to uplaod fairly normal like 100 Mb or greater Files, what I am doing I am genrating/requesting a signed url then via that I am making a put request to my bucket via react query and axios, but my app is crashing in the middel of the opration.

```
 [auth][error] JWTSessionError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#jwtsessionerror
[auth][cause]: Error: fetch failed
    at context.fetch (D:\galzzy.com\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_modules\next\dist\server\web\sandbox\context.js:272:38)
    at postJSON (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.14.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:150:28)
    at Connection.execute (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.14.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:102:29)
    at PlanetScalePreparedQuery.execute (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/drizzle-orm@0.29.3_@planetscale+database@1.14.0_@types+react@18.2.48_mysql2@3.8.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/drizzle-orm/planetscale-serverless/session.js:43:39)
    at QueryPromise.execute (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/drizzle-orm@0.29.3_@planetscale+database@1.14.0_@types+react@18.2.48_mysql2@3.8.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/drizzle-orm/mysql-core/query-builders/query.js:100:31)
    at QueryPromise.then (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/.pnpm/drizzle-orm@0.29.3_@planetscale+database@1.14.0_@types+react@18.2.48_mysql2@3.8.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/drizzle-orm/query-promise.js:28:21)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[auth][details]: {
  "name": "ConnectTimeoutError",
  "code": "UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT",
  "message": "Connect Timeout Error"
}
```

**This is the block of code that hanldes the video upload and I call it with**`useVideoUpload.mutateAsync()`

```
 `const useVideoUpload = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['upload-video-s3'],
    mutationFn: async () => {
      // requesting signed url
      const res = await axios.post('/api/channel/get-signed-url/', {
        fileName: videoFile?.name,
      });

      if (res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error(res.data);
      }
      const { data } = (await res.data) as {
        message: string;
        data: { url: string };
      };
      if (videoFile) {
        // putting the video file to the bucket
        console.log('[STRARTING VIDEO]');
        const response = await axios.put(data.url, videoFile, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': videoFile.type,
          },
        });
        console.log('[DONE VIDEO]');
        console.log({ response });
        return response;
      }
    },
  });`
```